# tuple index out of range when calling create_image on a Canvas object

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running a program with tkinter. I have put my code below as well as the error I'm facing:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("The password generator")
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
photo = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(x=100, y=100, image=photo)
canvas.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I am not able to get a window with an image, every time I run it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shaun\Downloads\password-manager-start\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    canvas.create_image(x=100,y=100,image=photo)
  File "C:\Users\shaun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2790, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\shaun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2771, in _create
    cnf = args[-1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By carefully inspecting the error trace, something problematic can be noticed. The [`create_image`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/90ab138bbdc63763ad825ed6d4821367c09c4015/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2816) function is:

```py
def create_image(self, *args, **kw):
    """Create image item with coordinates x1,y1."""
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
```

So all positional arguments are packed into an `args` tuple and all key-word arguments are packed into the `kw` dict. Then, they are passed ***as-is*** to the [`_create`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/90ab138bbdc63763ad825ed6d4821367c09c4015/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2796) function, without unpacking.

The way you call the function, `canvas.create_image(x=100, y=100, image=photo)`, means that you ***only pass key-word arguments***, and no positionals. This means that `args` will be an ***empty tuple***. Further ahead, `_create` expects some arguments in the `args` tuple which it doesn't find [in this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/90ab138bbdc63763ad825ed6d4821367c09c4015/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2799):

```
cnf = args[-1]
```

To overcome this, simply pass `x` and `y` as positionals:

```
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=photo)
```

This way they are packed into the `args` tuple and not the `kw` dict and `_create` can access the last item of that tuple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out time.....it worked